# Using MudBlazor in WPF Blazor App (Hybrid Solution)

Tags: wpf, blazor, mudblazor

I try to build a WPF Blazor App following this MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/wpf?view=aspnetcore-6.0). I try to add mudblazor along this [guide](https://mudblazor.com/getting-started/installation#using-our-dotnet-templates).

MainWindow Code Behind:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceCollection.AddWpfBlazorWebView();
        serviceCollection.AddMudServices();
        Resources.Add("services", serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider());
    }
```

Counter Razor Component:

```
<MudText Typo="Typo.h1">Counter</MudText>

<MudText Typo="Typo.h5">Current state: @currentCount</MudText>

<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Secondary" 
@onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</MudButton>

@code {
   private int currentCount = 0;

   private void IncrementCount()
   {
       currentCount++;
   }
}
```

The MudBlazor magic is sadly not visible, the result is :

[image]

Where I`m wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but in case someone else got caught with that...

You probably missed the last part of the guide, which states you must at least add `<MudThemeProvider />` on top of your `MainLayout.razor`.

Of course, in your case with WPF Hybrid, you won't have a MainLayout.razor.

Instead, you have to put that on top of your root razor component (Counter.razor in your case it seems).